# Opening URL inside iframe tag targeting parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, response.redirect

Problem: how to open URL from within iframe tag.

I have an asp.net web application, which includes a shopping cart located in a subfolder, although for test purposes another URL entirely.

I include a portion of the shopping cart on the main site using an iframe tag.

```
<iframe name="iCartInfo" id="Iframe1" runat="server" src="https://www.mysite.domain/shop/cart/MyShoppingCartLine.aspx" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" style="float: right; border: none; overflow-y: hidden;" width="380" height="40"></iframe>
```

If I include the

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

in the destination, then the request does not work. If I do not include the request, the URL opens in the iframe.

I traced the code that opens the URL to a button's code behind.

```
Response.Redirect("~/whatever.aspx");
```

I changed that to an absolute URL from a relative URL to see if that resolves the issue, when including the base tag in the head of the iframe page, but nope, nothing happens when I click. The nearest that I can see is that other pages or code gets affected by some means.

Is there any other way without upsetting the code inside the iframe to have the request open in the parent's browser window and not inside the iframe?

Comment: Can you clarify the scenario? Inside of IFRAME something redirects to "whatever.aspx" and you want that page to open in the parent instead of iframe and without touching code of "MyShoppingCartLine.aspx" ? Or is touching code inside IFRAME is an option?